# Why use =Cell(contents,x) in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

What is the usefulness of:

```
=Cell(contents,x)
```

Why not just:

```
=X
```

e.g. in this case wouldn't:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,2))
```

work the same as:

```
=CELL("contents",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,2)))
```

Comment: What does your initial question have to do with whether the two formulas would work the same?

Answer (score 4):

Cell contents returns only the value in the cell. This is often the only thing you need, and in many formulae it would be fine to use the =X in your example (the Cell function also gives you access to a lot more information about the cell though, eg type, etc).

However indirect lets you do more, as rather than just passing the value from a cell, it creates a reference to the cell, which could then be used in formulae. Cell contents won't let you do this.

Cell would let you do this:

```
A1="thing I'm looking up"
=vlookup(cell.contents("contents",A1), myRange,1,false)
```

or even this:

```
A1="B2"
B2="thing i'm looking up"
=vlookup(cell.contents("contents",indirect(A1)), myRange,1,false)
```

But it won't let you do this:

```
A1="B3:C5"
vlookup("thing I'm looking up in " & A1, indirect(A1), 1, false)
```

where you could use the address stored in A1 as a reference to be used in a formula. Cell only lets you use the value, and not as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

`CELL("contents",...)` returns

> Value of the upper-left cell in reference; not a formula

(https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf)

So the result of using the `CELL` function vs just referring to a range will be different if your reference contains multiple cells.